# EGit branching for multiple developers

Tags: git, egit

I have a project on which I work at office. But since i am nearing my deadline i also want to take a copy of my project to my home computer so that I can work at home as well. I am using eclipse with the EGit plug in 
           Is there a way that I can create a branch of the project carry it in an USB stick work on it on my computer  at home and return with the updated project on the USB stick to my office computer and merge the branch on the pen drive with the main branch on my office computer .
           Is it safe and what are the precautions should I take before I unsertake this task. I am new to git and sometimes find it very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clone a local repository on a USB stick using `git clone` command, work on it (create branches, add new commits, etc.) and later come back with your USB stick and push this work into the original repository. It will work, but if you are new to Git, and if you can, it will probably be easyer to create an online repository (Bitbucket allows you to create free private repos) and use it as a base to clones. This is the most common case for people working on many computers, even if they are alone on a project. And when you will be more comfortable with Git usage, you could clone your repo to an USB key.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to clone your project on your usb key (at work).

Work on it with the same branch as usual (at Home).

Commit your change (at Home).

Come back with your usb key (at Work).

Push your change from git bash for instance (at Work).

https://msysgit.github.io/
Open eclipse and pull on your branch.

I recommand you to use git bash on windows because EGit as some limitation for specific operation.